# Class objects stored in numpy.array() not working properly

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create an array of objects for the class value. But the values of all the objects become equal.

```
import numpy as np

class value:
  def store(self,jobid,deadline,profit):
    self.job = jobid
    self.deadline = deadline
    self.profit = profit

  def initialize(self):
    job = input()
    deadline = int(input())
    profit= int(input())
    self.store(job,deadline,profit)


def disp(arr,n):
  for i in range(n):
    print(str(arr[i].job)+" "+str(arr[i].deadline)+" "+str(arr[i].profit))


n=2
arr = np.array([None for i in range(n)])
val = value()

for i in range(n):
  val.initialize()
  arr[i]=val

disp(arr,n)
```

Input

```
A
2
3
B
2
1
```

Expected output
A 2 3
B 2 1

Output I am getting
B 2 1
B 2 1

What am I be doing wrong and what might fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating only one instance of your class with the initial call to `value()`. Calls to `initialize` and `store` just modify the content of that instance.

You then assign the same instance to all array elements.

To fix this, you need to create new instances by putting the `val = value()` inside the loop.